# Abaco en C sin vectores

Tags: c

Me gustaría saber si alguien puede llegar a explicarme este código de programación que desarrollé hasta cierto punto, pero que vi un ejemplo y así fue como salió, pero en realidad fue de pura suerte, pero me irrita no saber exactamente que está pasando, al final trata de simular un ábaco sin el uso de vectores:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string _Abaco(int n)
{
   int digito;
   string abaco;

   while(n > 0)
   {
      digito = n % 10;

      for(int i = 1; i <= digito; i++)
      {
         abaco += 'O';
      }

      abaco += '\n';
      n /= 10;
   }

   return abaco;
}

int main () 
{
   int n;

   cout<<"Ingrese el numero: "; cin>>n;
   cout<<"\nLa representacion del numero "<<n<<" en un abaco es: ";
   cout<<"\n\n"<<_Abaco(n);

   return 0;
}
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Por cada uno de los digitos empezando por la derecha, pones tantas `O` como sea el valor del digito.

Comment: C es similar a C++. Pero lo que estás usando es C++.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado suponga el numero 123, el operador % se aplica en

digito = 123 % 10 = 3
(Resto de la division entera)

Es importar notar que nada queda dividido, solo se calculó el resto, el numero 3 se usa para controlar el bucle for, que imprimirá:

000

Notar que estamos dentro del bucle while( n > 0), donde n es igual 123, ahora si se lo divide por 10, n = 12.

Nuevamente la division entera, el bucle for opera con 2

00

Nuevamente n = n / 10, entonces for operara con 1,

0

Por última se divide por 10, es que tendremos n = 0 y el while no termina